# Animation affecting siblings position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I have animation on one element but its movement affects siblings as well. How can I have animation only on item without affecting siblings element?

Example of problem:

```
function animateSearch() {
   $('.glyphicon-search').animate({'margin-top':'-10px'}, 1000);
   $('.glyphicon-search').animate({'margin-top':'0px'}, 1000);

 }
 var interval = setInterval(animateSearch,1000);

$('.arrowDown').mouseover(function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
});
```

DEMO: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2zrpmw4v/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put Css `postion:absolue` rule  like bellow :

```
.glyphicon-search {
   position:absolute;
}
```

Fiddle [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/2zrpmw4v/1/)